# how to convert int array into comma seperated in swift

Tags: swift

in my app i have taken an object, lets say var selectedIds = Int. i want this selectedIds to be comma seperated. because i need to send selectedids to next screen in which api calling has parameters which is comma seperated. i should get ids like 556,573 so that i can pass into parameters of receiving controller

the viewcontroller file from which i want to send selectedIds array:

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var store_bar: UIViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var store_title: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var category_title: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var category_bar: UIViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryColView: UICollectionView!

    var selectedBtnIndex:Int = 1
    var selectedIds = [Int]()
    var storeIds = [Int]()

    var categoryData = [ModelCategories]()
    var storeData = [ModelStore]()


    var arrCategoryImages = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // register collectionview cell
        self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1")
        self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoresCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell")

        self.store_bar.isHidden = true

        self.getCategoriesList()
        self.getStoreList()


    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {

        if sender.isSelected == true {
            selectedIds.append(categoryData[sender.tag].ID!)
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
            sender.isSelected = false

        }else {

            selectedIds = selectedIds.filter{ $0 != sender.tag }
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }

    @objc func click_store(sender: UIButton!) {

        if sender.isSelected == true {
            selectedIds.append(storeData[sender.tag].ID!)
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
            sender.isSelected = false
        }else {
            selectedIds = selectedIds.filter{ $0 != sender.tag }
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }


    //MARK: IBActions

    @IBAction func categoriesData(_ sender: UIButton) {

        selectedBtnIndex = 1
        self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
        self.store_bar.isHidden = true
        self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.category_bar.isHidden = false
        self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
        self.categoryColView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func storeData(_ sender: UIButton) {

        selectedBtnIndex = 2
        self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
        self.store_bar.isHidden = false
        self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.category_bar.isHidden = true
        self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
        self.categoryColView.reloadData()

    }

    @IBAction func showHomeScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        if selectedBtnIndex == 1 {
            vc.selectedIds = self.selectedIds
//          vc.couponId = categoryData[sender.tag].ID!
        }else {
            vc.selectedIds = self.selectedIds
        }

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
    }

    @IBAction func toSearchPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPageController") as! SearchPageController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
    }

    func getCategoriesList() {
        if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

            APIClient<ModelBaseCategoryList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_CategoriesList, Params: [:], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

                if(modelResponse.success == true) {
                    self.categoryData.removeAll()
                    let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.categories! as NSArray

                    if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                        for i in modelResponse.categories! {
                            if i.count != 0 {
                                if let image = UIImage(named: "\(i.slug!.uppercased())") {
                                    self.arrCategoryImages.append(image)
                                    self.categoryData.append(i)
                                }else {
                                    self.arrCategoryImages.append(UIImage(named: "tickets")!)
                                    self.categoryData.append(i)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
                }
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
                self.categoryColView.reloadData()
            }) { (failed) in
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
                self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
        }
    }

    func getStoreList() {
        if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

            APIClient<ModelBaseStoreList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_StoreList, Params: [:], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

                if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                    self.storeData.removeAll()
                    let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.store! as NSArray

                    if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                        for i in modelResponse.store! {
                            if i.count != 0 {
                                self.storeData.append(i)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
                }
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
                self.categoryColView.reloadData()
            }) { (failed) in
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
                self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
        }
    }
}


//MARK: Delegate and Data Source Methods
extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
            return categoryData.count
        }else {
            return storeData.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1

            let dict = categoryData[indexPath.row]

            if let catName = dict.name, catName.count != 0 {
                cell.categoryName.text = catName
            }

            if let catOffersCount = dict.count {

                if catOffersCount == 1 {
                  cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offer"
                }else {
                    cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offers"
                }
            }

            cell.categoryImage.image = arrCategoryImages[indexPath.row]

            cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)

            if selectedIds.contains(categoryData[indexPath.row].ID!) {
                cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
                cell.btn_click.isSelected = true
            }else {
                cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
                cell.btn_click.isSelected = false
            }

            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell", for: indexPath) as! StoresCell

            let dict = storeData[indexPath.row]

            if let storeName = dict.name, storeName.count != 0 {
                cell.storeName.text = storeName
            }

            if let storeOfferCount = dict.count {
                cell.storeOfferCount.text = "\(storeOfferCount)"+" "+"Offers"
            }

            cell.store_btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.store_btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_store), for: .touchUpInside)


            if selectedIds.contains(storeData[indexPath.row].ID!) {
                cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .normal)
                cell.store_btn_click.isSelected = true
            }else {
                cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
                cell.store_btn_click.isSelected = false
            }

            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
           return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3, height: 93)
        }else {
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 2, height: 48)
        }
    }
```

The viewcontroller file in which i want selectedIds array:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var couponsData = [ModelCoupons]()

    var couponId = Int()
    var selectedIds = [Int]()

    @IBOutlet weak var homeTblView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.homeTblView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell")
        self.post_CouponsData()

        print(selectedIds)

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    //MARK: IBActions
    @IBAction func toCategoryScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func toSearchPage(_ sender: UIButtonX) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPageController") as! SearchPageController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func post_CouponsData() {
        if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {

            var params = [String : String]()

            params ["term_ids"] = "\(self.selectedIds)"

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)

            APIClient<ModelBaseCouponsList>().API_POST(Url: SD_POST_CouponsList, Params: params as [String:AnyObject], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

                if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

                    let dict = modelResponse.coupons
                    for i in dict! {
                        self.couponsData.append(i)
                    }

                }else {
                    self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
                }
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
                self.homeTblView.reloadData()

            }) { (failed) in
                self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            }
        }else {
            self.view.makeToast("No internet connection...")
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
        }
    }
}


extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return couponsData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        let dict = couponsData[indexPath.row]

        if let postTitle = dict.postTitle, postTitle.count != 0 {
            cell.ticket_postTitle.text = postTitle
        }
        if let postContent = dict.postContent, postContent.count != 0 {
            cell.ticket_postContent.text = postContent
        }
        if let storeName = dict.stores, storeName.count != 0 {
            cell.storename.text = storeName
        }

        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

        let datee = ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.ConvertStingTodate(forApp: dict.validTill!)
        cell.ticket_ValidDate.text = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: datee)

        cell.ticketImageView.tintColor = .random()
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 339.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 339.0
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can you remove the code that is not related to your question so that readers can focus on the relevant parts? You will have a better chance of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert an array of `Int`s to an array of strings using

```
selectedIds.map(String.init)
```

and then convert that array of strings into a single string like this

```
selectedIds.map(String.init).joined(separator: ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map the `Int` array to `String` array and then `join` the array with separator comma to get a comma separated string.

```
params["term_ids"] = self.selectedIds.map(String.init).joined(separator: ",")
```